# Multipage TIFF image created with PIL larger than individual frames

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, tiff

I am trying to group batches of images (.jpeg) and create a multipage TIFF file for each batch using Python and Pillow.

Using the `append_images` argument in `save()`, the files I get are much larger than the original.
Considering a batch of 15 jpeg images (total size 643kB), the resulting TIFF is 6.29MB with no compression.

Is there a way to reduce the file size, possibly without using compression, and get a TIFF file with size similar to the one of all the original files?

```
import os
from PIL import Image

sourcedir = os.getcwd()
savedir = os.path.join(sourcedir,'TIFF')
batch = ['Im-00', 'Im-01', 'Im-02', 'Im-03', 'Im-04', 'Im-05', 'Im-06', 'Im-07', 'Im-08', 'Im-09', 'Im-10', 'Im-11', 'Im-12', 'Im-13', 'Im-14']

batch_counter = 0
imlistA = []
filenameA = ["A-" + s + ".jpg" for s in batch]
for fileA in filenameA:
        filepath = os.path.join(sourcedir,fileA)
        imlistA.append(Image.open(filepath))
        TIFFnameA = 'A-batch-0'+str(batch_counter)+'.tiff'
        TIFFdirA = os.path.join(savedir,TIFFnameA)
        imlistA[0].save(TIFFdirA, compression=None, save_all=True,
                append_images=imlistA[1:])
```

Comment: what is the difference between a single jpg image and its corresponded tiff version ?

Comment: I tried with a single image and the file size increased from 84KB (jpeg) to 1033KB (tiff)

Comment: not an expert here but reading around seems like TIFF is a container format (a “file system in a file”) for images with tagged data. For example, it can contain different channels of data, or high and low resolution versions, or multiple pages..... not sure how but you need to figureout how to save images with the right resolution see:  https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes maybe you are saving them as 32bit when 8bit are enough ...

Comment: print the Image.mode < print(img.mode) > of both jpg and saved tiff and see if are the same

Comment: dont know how big a tiff thumbnail could be

Comment: It turns out that the file size is the same if I convert the original JPEG to TIFF using Irfanview. I also tried checking the image mode and resolution and bpp are the same. I guess compression is the only thing left to try to reduce the file size

Comment: to investigate your images you can use https://exiftool.org/

Comment: TIFF files are lossless formats. This means there is no compression of the image when it is saved and/or converted to a TIFF file. A JPEG file has an algorithm that compresses many of the colors in order to reduce file size. It looks at every pixel and if it has used that color in a previous location within the image it just refers the color to the previous identification. The down side to this is that it has a tolerance level for the actual color and isn't exactly the same as the original color.

Comment: Therefore your file size may be smaller, but it has few colors pixel by pixel. An original TIFF file may have millions of colors within the image while the same image in JPEG format could be only in the hundreds of thousands. It doesn't sound like a loss but it is. The best comparison is an MP3 file is compressed while the CDR (compact disk recording) file is not, in audio terms.  [not mine got from web forum]